# File uploaded does not upload if the file name has parenthesis ()

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, ajax, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control where I upload PDF files and they get saved to a folder, the file path gets saved to the database.

The problem is when I upload a file which contains parenthesis () as part of the file name, it returns undefined. This only happens if the file name has parenthesis () , if it does not have parenthesis () it uploads fine.

This is my code

```
var filePaths;
function UploadFile() {

    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fuPDFupload");
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.png|.pdf)$");
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {

        //Check whether HTML5 is supported.
        if (typeof (fileUpload.files) != "undefined") {
            //Initiate the FileReader object.
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //Read the contents of Image File.
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
                var image = new Image();

                //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
                image.src = e.target.result;


                var fileUpload = $("#fuPDFupload").get(0);
                var files = fileUpload.files;

                var data = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "FileUploadHandler.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        filePaths = result;
                        //Save to DB
                        UpdateSchedule();
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                    }
                });
                return true;
            };


        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

FileUploadHandler Code:

```
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                string filePaths = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];
                string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/QfrencyInvoices/" + filePaths);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(filePaths);
            }
        }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I believe that the problem might be happening because the Regex expression is incorrect but I have not been able to fix it.
Please assist me how I can upload files that have parenthesis () as part of the file name. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to modify the regex expression so that the brackets are included?

Comment: I have tried but I have not succeeded. I am not sure if I have structured the regex expression correctly

Comment: escape like this: `\(` and `\)` because the round bracket is part of regex syntax (grouping). But: why would you? someone must have come up with that regex in first place, to intentionally limit what can be uploaded. there should be a requirement/rule, otherwise the whole test makes no sense. Or at least return a meaningful message to users, just rejecting with no reason will confuse them a lot. a bullet-proof file upload security check always involves file byte signature testing, like libmagic, filenames can be spoofed.

Comment: File (AND filename) check/modifying must be done on server side, otherwise a malicious code injection would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave next regex `new RegExp("(\.(jpg|png|pdf)$", "i");`. It checks that filename has extension jpg, png or pdf. Text case does not matter so "i" was added as the second parameter.

You can learn regular expressions on https://regexone.com/

Comment: Should I change my regex expression what you suggested? new RegExp("(\.(jpg|png|pdf)$", "i");

Comment: This worked fine for me: var regex = new RegExp("\.+(.jpg|.png|.pdf)$");